# GCP - Create postgreSQL through terraform - with VPC

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

In GCP cloud, I tried to create PostgreSQL through terraform. my org policy doesn't allow to create for public ip. I have to use private ip or VPC. I already created VPC and wanted to use that for creating postgresql.

Here is the code I tried. I don't know where to give VPC.

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "master" {
  database_version = "POSTGRES_9_6"
  region = "europe-west1"
  settings {
    tier = "db-f1-micro"
    availability_type = "ZONAL"
  }
}
```

Comment: There are many tutorials regarding this same case use. Please give it a try and if you have any specific issue post it here https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-deploy-a-cloud-sql-db-with-a-private-ip-only-using-terraform-e184b08eca64

Answer (score 2):

As @gopalakrishnan mentioned, the way to do it is adding `ip_configuration` to the template:

```
ip_configuration {
      ipv4_enabled    = false
      private_network = <VPC_FULL_PATH_NAME>
    }
```

A full sample can be found in this [Medium Article](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-deploy-a-cloud-sql-db-with-a-private-ip-only-using-terraform-e184b08eca64) or in the Terraform [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_database_instance#private-ip-instance).

Answer (score -2):

As per this [github](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-sql-db/tree/master/examples/postgresql-public) you can create Postgres Clod SQL database using Terraform.

```
/**
 * Copyright 2019 Google LLC
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

provider "google" {
  version = "~> 3.22"
}

provider "google-beta" {
  version = "~> 3.5"
}

provider "null" {
  version = "~> 2.1"
}

provider "random" {
  version = "~> 2.2"
}

module "postgresql-db" {
  source               = "../../modules/postgresql"
  name                 = var.db_name
  random_instance_name = true
  database_version     = "POSTGRES_9_6"
  project_id           = var.project_id
  zone                 = "us-central1-c"
  region               = "us-central1"
  tier                 = "db-f1-micro"

  deletion_protection = false

  ip_configuration = {
    ipv4_enabled        = true
    private_network     = null
    require_ssl         = true
    authorized_networks = var.authorized_networks
  }
}
```

Comment: I followed this git repo and it throws the same error.

Error: Error, failed to create instance example-postgres-public-3f6e41c6: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid request: Organization Policy check failure: the external IP of this instance violates the constraints/sql.restrictPublicIp enforced

Comment: This doesn't actually show how to specify a private network

Comment: I got the answer from my friend.

  ip_configuration = {
    ipv4_enabled        = false
    private_network     = <VPCName with full path>
    require_ssl         = true
  }